# Keyword not supported: initial catalog

Tags: c#

i searched the web and stack too, find some topic but none of them solve the problem
and problem : i can't connect to database with the error **"Keyword not supported: initial catalog"** 
enter image description here[My so plain code!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sG9HZ.jpg)

[image]

[Evil Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hb8HK.jpg)
[image]

Comment: Remove the carriage return and leave it as "Initial catalog", only one space.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow - please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/How-to-ask) as links are frowned up on as they go missing and then the questions mean nothing, please post code, errors etc directly to your question

Comment: And to be more exact don't paste code as screen shots, it's text, post it as text...

Comment: ... and the real evil is your SqlDataAdapter query being [vulnerable to SQL Injection](http://xkcd.com/327/) ... always use parameters.

Comment: you'r right @Filburt , I'm here to learn and will sanitize that Evil

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a new line between `"Initial"` and `"Catalog"`. Replace it with a space, or consider using a `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` to construct the connection string programatically.